# How to restrict params Rails passes to an object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, security

How can I exclude (or explicitly include) params passed to an object like in the following example:

```
  def create
    @something = Something.new(params[:something])
    ...
    @something.save    
  end
```

Say for example `something` had a field `trust_level` that should not be settable through public users (which are allowed to create the object). It would be easy to send this field via HTTP even if the provided form doesn't contain it. So how can be prevented that this field is passed to the `new` (or `update_attributes`) method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`attr_accessible`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) to define what's available to mass-assignment.

(That's a [link to the docs](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveModel/MassAssignmentSecurity/ClassMethods/attr_accessible) but it's a little hard to tell, so here it is again.)

Comment: Although whitelists are safer than blacklists, if you'd rather just exclude specific fields from mass-assignment, you can also use the `attr_protected` class method.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is to [filter out unwanted](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core/classes/Hash.html#M000752) params. Just in case you want to get rid only of a specific param and you can't use attr_accessible (which is a better solution to your problem).

> ```
> hsh.reject {| key, value | block } → a_hash
> ```
>
> Same as `Hash#delete_if`,
>   but works on (and returns) a copy of the hsh. Equivalent to
>   hsh.dup.delete_if.
>
> ```
> enum.reject {| obj | block } → array
> enum.reject → an_enumerator
> ```